# show that the relation give by $\vert x \vert=\vert y \vert$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, relations, equivalence-relations

For the relation $$\vert x \vert = \vert y \vert$$

this consists of all the pairs $(\vert -a \vert,\vert a \vert)$

Clearly $$\vert x \vert = \vert x \vert$$ and $$\vert y \vert = \vert y \vert$$

for example $\vert 2 \vert = \vert 2 \vert$ and say $\vert 4 \vert = \vert 4 \vert$

Thus the relation is reflexive

Clearly if $\vert x \vert = \vert y \vert$ then $\vert y \vert = \vert x \vert$

for example $\vert 3 \vert =\vert -3 \vert$ or $\vert -3 \vert = \vert 3 \vert$

Thus the relation is symmetric

If $\vert x \vert = \vert y \vert$ and $\vert y \vert = \vert z \vert$

Clearly $\vert x \vert = \vert z \vert$

Thus the relation is transitive.

Not sure how to show an example for the transitive property. I feel like this relation is pretty much self explanatory. Am I right that this consists of the pairs $(\vert -a \vert,\vert a \vert)$? Are my proofs without the examples acceptable? Are my examples correct? Can I improve my answer at all?

Comment: Make it more abstract. If $f \colon X \to Y$ is any function, then the relation $a \sim b \iff f(a) = f(b)$ is an equivalence relation. That also avoids the awkwardness of dealing with transitivity when one knows that all equivalence classes have at most two members.

Comment: when you wrote $(|-a|,| a|)$, did you mean $(-|a|,|a|)$ or $(a,-a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the transitive property you could show that
Since $|x|=|y|$ then $|x|-|y|=0$.
Since $|y|=|z|$ then $|y|-|z|=0$.
Then
$$0=\\0+0=\\(|x|-|y|)+(|y|-|z|)=\\|x|-|z|$$
Since $0=|x|-|z|$ then $|x|=|z|$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make examples: you just need to prove the property.

> Suppose $|x|=|y|$ and $|y|=|z|$. Then $|x|=|z|$.

That's all.

More generally, if you have a function $f\colon X\to Y$ and define the relation $\sim_{f}$ on $X$ by
$$
a\sim_{f}b \quad\text{if and only if}\quad f(a)=f(b)
$$
then $\sim_f$ is an equivalence relation:

1. $a\sim_f a$ follows from $f(a)=f(a)$
2. if $a\sim_f b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$, so $f(b)=f(a)$ and therefore $b\sim_fa$
3. if $a\sim_f b$ and $b\sim_f c$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(b)=f(c)$, so $f(a)=f(c)$ and therefore $a\sim_f c$

Your case is $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(a)=|a|$.

---

You seem to be baffled by the fact that there are no *distinct* $a,b,c$ such that $|a|=|b|$ and $|b|=|c|$. That's completely irrelevant for the task of proving transitivity.

Actually, having proved reflexivity, you can, *in this particular case*, even dispense from proving transitivity, because it *cannot* be false. But there's no need to go this way.

Comment: Indeed.  Furthermore, not only do you not *need* to provide examples, it is not *sufficient* to do so.  A specific example does not prove the general case.